# How to send a print job from ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, printing, webforms

How do you send a print job to a printer from ASP Web Forms?

I am working on a project for a **school fee system**. I want to print a document of all the class fees from a series of search criteria (either for a group of students or singular).

For example, at the start of the month it should print a document of all the fees of `class X` or select student(s) will have to pay.

So far I have tried storing the search results using `dt` but I don't understand how I send the fee document to a printer.

Comment: Take a look at a javascript solution google "js print document" if you want the clients to print on their own printer. If you want the server to send a print job to a centralized system or access a pre-specified printer then asp.net is the man for the job. the just google "print document C#"

Comment: Cleaned up the question for readability. Not certain what the reference to `dt` is however, so I have left this as is.

Comment: dt is datatable